# Regex pattern to split colon char with a condition

Tags: java, regex

I have a string like this :

```
http://schemas/identity/claims/usertype:External
```

Then my goal is to split that string into 2 words by colon delimiter, but in need to specified how the regex worked, it will be split the colon but not including colon in "http://", so those strings will be split into :

```
http://schemas/identity/claims/usertype
External
```

I have tried regex like this :

```
(http:\/\/+schemas\/identity\/claims\/usertype)
```

So it will be :

```
http://schemas/identity/claims/usertype
:External
```

then after that i will replace the remaining colon with empty string.

but i think its not a best practice for this, because i rarely used regex.
Do you have any suggestion to simplified the regex ?

Thanks in advance

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is an X/Y problem. Fortunately, you asked the question in a great way, by explaining the underlying problem you are trying to solve (namely: Pull some string out of a URL), and then describing the direction you've chosen to solve your problem (which is bad, see below), and then asking about a problem you have with this solution (which is irrelevant, as the entire solution is bad).

URLs aren't parsable like this. You shouldn't treat them as a string you can lop into pieces like this. For example, the server part can contain colons too: For port number. In front of the server part, there can be an authentication which can also contain a colon. It's rarely used, of course.

Try this one, which shows the problem with your approach:

https://joe:joe@google.com:443/

That link just works. Port 443 was the default anyway, and google ignores the authentication header that ends up sending, but the point is, a URL may contain this stuff.

*But rzwitserloot, it.. won't! I know!*

That's bad programming mindset. That mindset leads to security issues. Why go for a solution that burdens your codebase with unstated assumptions (assumption: The places that provide a URL to this code are under my control and will never send port or auth headers)? If the 'server' part is configurable in a config file, will you mention in said config file that you cannot add a port? Will you remember 4 years from now?

The solution that does it right isn't going to burden your code with all these unstated (or very unwieldy if stated) assumptions.

### Okay, so what is the right way?

First, toss that string into the constructor of `java.net.URI`. Then, use the methods there to get what you actually want, which is the `path` part. *That* is a string you can pull apart:

```
URI uri = new URI("http://schemas/identity/claims/usertype:External");
String path = uri.getPath();
String newPath = path.replaceAll(":.*", "");
String type = path.replaceAll(".*?:", "");
URI newUri = uri.resolve(newPath);
System.out.println(newUri);
System.out.println(type);
```

prints:

```
http://schemas/identity/claims/usertype
External
```

NB: Toss some ports or auth stuff in there, or make it a relative URL - do whatever you like, this code is far more robust in the face of changing the base URL than any attempt to count colons is going to be.

Answer (score 0):

**Use Negative Lookbehind and split**

**Regex:**

```
"(?<!(http|https)):"
```

**Regex in context:**

```
public static void main(String[] args) {
    String input = "http://schemas/identity/claims/usertype:External";
    validateURI(input);
    List<String> result = Arrays.asList(input.split("(?<!(http|https)):"));
    result.forEach(System.out::println);
}

private static void validateURI(String input) {
    try {
        new URI(input);
    } catch (URISyntaxException e) {
        System.out.println("Invalid URI!!!");
        e.printStackTrace();
    }
}
```

**Output:**

```
http://schemas/identity/claims/usertype
External
```

Answer (score -1):

I think this might help you:

```
public class Separator{
    public static void main(String[] args) {
        String input = "http://schemas/identity/claims/usertype:External";
        String[] splitted = input.split("\\:");
        System.out.println(splitted[splitted.length-1]); 
    }
}
```

**Output**

```
External
```

Comment: appreciated your help, but the desired string[] output is (without brackets) :

1. [http://schemas/identity/claims/usertype]
2. [External]